# How can I overwrite a models.py entry only if the user id is the current user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, userid

I have genome files, and I want each user to be able to upload their own genome file, but they can only have one of them. I want it so that if they try to upload another, then they will just replace the genome and form data for their last entry.

I am using their entries, along with n number of people who use the site (each person also having 1 entry per person) as samples to analyze against that person's genome, so I want to keep a models file full of genomes, names, sex, etc... but only one per user.

Here's my models.py file

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

    SEX_CHOICES = (
       ('M', 'Male'),
       ('F', 'Female')
    )

    class Genome(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        CHOICES = [('M','Male'),('F','Female')]
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default='M')
        genome = models.FileField(upload_to='users/genomes/')
        #id = request.user.id
        #if id is the current user then replace old data with new data


        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

and here is my views function

```
    def upload(request):
        context = {}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = GenomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('My-DNA.html')
            else:
                form = GenomeForm()

          
            return render(request, 'my-DNA.html', {context})
        else:
            print("failure")

        form = GenomeForm()
        return render(request, 'Upload.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

I just want a way to limit the user to one response while still having a list of many genomes from other people to compare it to.

Thanks

Comment: Why you cant update the file by the views thats so easy

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that? that seems like it would work. How can I check to see if there is data there before updating it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding another field in model.

```
class Genome(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    CHOICES = [('M','Male'),('F','Female')]
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default='M')
    genome = models.FileField(upload_to='users/genomes/')


    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
```

Here by adding user as a onetoOneField, One User can only create one genome document. If you want ,multiple genome document you can use foreignKey field.
See OneToOne doc : [OnoToOne doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)
Foreign Key doc: [Foreign Key doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Then you can check in view that user has genome document or not.
If has then simply update or create a new genome document.

You can check by filtering in view:

```
Genome.objects.filter(user=user).first()
```

Here filter return a queryset and by calling first() you can get the first document in that queryset or if not found it simply return none.